# apt-get dist-upgrade hangs

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, updates, google-chrome

I just ran an update of 14.04 followed by a dist-upgrade and the the upgrade hangs while trying to set up google chrome.    The following indicates as far as I was able to get.

```
Setting up linux-headers-4.2.0-35-generic (4.2.0-35.40~14.04.1) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 4.2.0-35-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-35-generic
Setting up linux-headers-generic-lts-wily (4.2.0.35.28) ...
Setting up linux-generic-lts-wily (4.2.0.35.28) ...
Setting up google-chrome-stable (49.0.2623.112-1) ..
```

I `ctrl c`-d out and tried to run `dpkg --configure -a` to repair the problem.   I got back to exactly the same place.   Similarly, running 
`apt-get install f` led to the same place.    At some point along the way, this was generated by the `dkpg --configure -a` command:

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-35-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-chrome-stable
 linux-headers-4.2.0-35-generic
 linux-headers-generic-lts-wily
 linux-generic-lts-wily
 linux-signed-generic-lts-wily
```

Can anybody advise how to proceed, please?

Thanks, Leo

Comment: remove google chrome and re-install  after upgrade?

Comment: Tried to do that with `apt-get --purge remove google-chrome-stable` and received `dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.`  But dpkg continues to hang at the same place.    Is there another way to remove the package?

Comment: synaptic package manager... aptitude... umm maually removing all the files and references